# How to activate a trigger on my contract when an address (contract or wallet) receives tokens?

Tags: solidity

Suppose that when the liquidity of an ERC20 token is added to the liquidity pool it generates some trigger for my contract to execute something.

Or suppose a wallet receives a token. This receipt **IMMEDIATELY** triggers my contract.

I tried to make a  `while` function that reads  `balanceOf` (which will be zero at the beginning) and stops when the balance of a wallet is different from  `zero` . However, it seems that this method consumes a lot of gas and reaches the limit. Even though query is free, it seems that the network does not process it.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this trigger issue?

Additional detail: the token or liquidity contract is from a third party and is already deployed on the mainnet.

Comment: Please, add more details or add an example at your question

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would like to create a smart contract that checks the balance of a liquidity contract when the liquidity is posted. This can be used for many cases, such as flash loan, pancakeswap trading contract.
I don't see how to be able to execute something in the contract through a trigger. This trigger would be when any wallet receives tokens from any other contract that has already been deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Called a keeper.  A lot of services out there (keeper.network, LINK, and others).  You can either use one of these services (where you fund a wallet and have bots perform the action for a reward), or you can do the likely cheaper but more work option of just standing up a server with a listener and a script (just listen for events or monitor for your specific case and then run the script)